# Print path to variable

Tags: powershell, cmd

What is the command for to print the environment variable in powershell ? In cmd it is `%path%` but its not working for me in `powershell`

Comment: Have you made any effort to find the answer yourself? Use Get-ChildItem Env:

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the command `Get-ChildItem Env:` to get all environment variables. If you want only path then use `Get-ChildItem Env:Path`

Comment: Thanks ! I also found out that $Env:Path works. But $Env: to display all the environment variables does not

Comment: you can use -split ";" to line break the string using $env:path